# Главный класс и второстепенный swing

Tags: java, swing, gui

Вот что-то не пойму. Моздаю проект в нетбинс. По дефолту класс главный создался. Добавляю jframe. Он второстепенный. Вопрос такой. Откидывать главный, назначать главным jframe и там весь код писать? Или в главно написать код, и вызывать его кнопками из jframe?

Comment: а что такое "главный" класс? или "второстепенный" ? поподробнее с этого места. Похоже какой-то новый термин в Яве?

Answer (score 1):

Не существует никаких "главных" и "второстепенных" классов. Пишите код там, где ему место.

Comment: Посыл, безусловно, верный, однако, стоило бы объяснить где, собственно, место коду. Сейчас ваш ответ выглядит как "вы творите такую страшную фигню, что я даже не стану объяснять, как правильно, всё равно не поймёте".